# Calling a method on a lambda expression without requiring a variable declaration

Tags: c#, methods, lambda

Given this extension method

```
    public static void Until(this Action action, Func<bool> booleanFunc)
    {
        while (!booleanFunc())
            action();
    }
```

is it possible to turn this

```
        var x = 0;

        Action ac = () => x += 1;
        ac.Until(() => x == 5);
```

into something of this sort

```
        var x = 0;

        (() => x += 1).Until(() => x == 5);
```

That is, a one liner?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Haven't you heard of while loops?

Comment: Just messing around with Ruby and was wondering how something like "until" could be implemented in .Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well lambdas need a type.  Saying `() => x += 1` alone says nothing about the delegate it is supposed to represent.  So provide the type of the lambda by passing it into the constructor.

```
new Action(() => x += 1).Until(() => x == 5);
```

A cast works as well.

```
((Action)(() => x += 1)).Until(() => x == 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately such syntax is not possible because the compiler cannot infer the type of the anonymous expression. It could be Action but it also could be some other custom defined delegate. You will need to cast it to `Action`.

Comment: But there's only an extension method on Action, not on any other kind of delegate. Looking just at the extension method part of the spec, it looks fine... but I suspect the problem is that the compiler can't check for normal instance methods (e.g. Invoke) without knowing the type.

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting - I [discovered the same thing a while ago](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/01/08/extension-methods-on-lamdba-expressions-don-t-work-unfortunately.aspx).

Extension method invocations are described in section 7.6.5.2 of the C# spec, and it seems to me that all of the conditions there are met... because that talks in terms of an expression being implicitly convertible to the first parameter type (which it is, in this case). That suggests that either there's a bug in the compiler (possible, but unlikely) or that one of the earlier conditions for it being a valid method call isn't met.

I suspect the problem is that a lambda expression isn't a *primary-expression* in spec terminology - unfortunately, my spec-fu isn't up to much this morning due to a cold. A lot of the rest of the method invocation machinery probably relies on knowing the type of the target of the method, which isn't known in this case.

Note that the other conspicuous "untyped expression" has the same problem - you can't call extension methods on a `null` literal, either.

Very occasionally this limitation is a pain, but most of the time I don't have much of an issue with it - and I suspect it makes the compiler a lot simpler to implement...